# Reading json file with multiple objects in java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have written a program that reads a simple json file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try {
        JSONArray a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("C:/Users/Zonoid/Desktop/EQ.json"));
        for (Object o : a)
        {
            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) o;
            String city = (String) obj.get("CITY");
            System.out.println("City : " + city);
            String loc = (String) obj.get("LOCATION");
            System.out.println("Location : " + loc);
            long el = (Long) obj.get("E_LEVEL");
            System.out.println("Emergency Level : " + el);
            long depth = (Long) obj.get("DEPTH");
            System.out.println("Depth : " + depth);
            long i = (Long) obj.get("INTENSITY");
            System.out.println("Intensity :"+i);
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

with my json file being:

```
[{"CITY":"MUMBAI","LOCATION":"a" ,"E_LEVEL": 6,"DEPTH":10,"INTENSITY":5},
{"CITY":"MUMBAI","LOCATION":"b" ,"E_LEVEL": 8,"DEPTH":20,"INTENSITY":4},
{"CITY":"MUMBAI","LOCATION":"c" ,"E_LEVEL": 3,"DEPTH":13,"INTENSITY":5},
{"CITY":"MUMBAI","LOCATION":"d" ,"E_LEVEL": 6,"DEPTH":12,"INTENSITY":4},]
```

I am working on a project that deals with earthquake alerts and want to read their JSON files however I cannot import them in JSON Array. The file I want to import looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "metadata": {
    "generated": 1488472809000,
    "url": "https:\/\/earthquake.usgs.gov\/earthquakes\/feed\/v1.0\/summary\/significant_week.geojson",
    "title": "USGS Significant Earthquakes, Past Week",
    "status": 200,
    "api": "1.5.4",
    "count": 2
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "mag": 5.5,
        "place": "42km WSW of Anchor Point, Alaska",
        "time": 1488420690658,....
```

Please tell what changes should be made.

Comment: What is wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: it gives the error org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray
 at practice.json.main(json.java:17)

Comment: I see now. You need to change your json file. The json file contains a object (it starts with { and ends with }. You want it to be an object array (starts with [{ and ends with }].

Comment: First if I am correct you are working on `Udacity project app` and from the site what you get is JSON object in that you have features array from where you should be extracting the objects not directly from the data for have in file

Comment: I tried that but it didn't remove the error

Comment: Your second JSON file is *totally* different from the first one, and you try to run the same code? Of course that doesn't work. --- And you're asking *us* to re-write the code for you? Sorry, SO is not a code-writing service. If you could figure out how to write the code for the first one, what *specific* part of writing code for the second one is troubling you? Hint: The code will be as different as the JSON is.

Comment: yeah I need to extract information from feature part. I am working on a project for earthquake early warning for college. I made some changes to the code and am not asking for the code. Please indicate the changes as I can't remove the error.   I want to read features array but I can not import the json file either in an object or JSONArray.

Comment: which one is the file format `[{"CITY":"MUMBAI","LOCATION":"a" ,"E_LEVEL": 6,"DEPTH":10,"INTENSITY":5},..` or the other one if its second one then the way you are parsing json is wrong

Comment: second one is not parsing properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  you are trying to read from features only, first you need to read the whole file as an object. Then you can, read the array part in the following way:

```
Object object = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:/Users/Zonoid/Desktop/EQ.json"));
JSONObject jasonObject = (JSONObject) object;
JSONArray features = (JSONArray) jasonObject.get("features");
```

Comment: ok, my mistake was directly using  JSONObject with parser.parse without converting it. Thanks for the help